# Clickable list box in tkinter

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to make a program that has a list of files and then people can click on those files in the list box and then it will open those files in another window.

Is there anyway I can do this? I have done research on it but sadly there was nothing I could find, from what I did find was just about the config and not actual selection.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: here you go: `http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it. When you create the listbox, you'll want to create a binding to `<<ListboxSelect>>` event. This event triggers whenever someone selects an item from the listbox. Alternatively, you could bind to `<Double-1>` if you want the file to open on a double click.

"Open those files in another window" is too vague to give a concrete answer, but it's possible and fairly easy. It depends on what you mean by "another window", and what type of files you're opening. Normally you would use a text widget if the data is text, and perhaps a canvas or label widget if the data is an image or some sort of drawing instructions.